# How to words in list in an embed | discordpy?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want to show the words I have in a list to the user, I have used the 'for' loop but this loop sends as many messages as all the words in the list

For example: 3 words are in a list, I want to send these three words once but it sends three times

**code :**

```
    @commands.command(name="showwords")
    async def showwords(self,context):
        if context.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            for word in config.WORDS:
                NOW_WORD = "\n".join(config.WORDS)
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="**Forbidden words :**",
                    description=f"||{NOW_WORD}||\n",
                    color=0x00FF00,
                )
                embed.set_footer(
                    text=f"Requested by {context.message.author}"
                )

                embed_message = await context.send(embed=embed)
                await embed_message.add_reaction("")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Error!",
                description="You don't have the permission to use this command.",
                color=0x00FF00,
            )
            embed_message = await context.send(embed=embed)
            await embed_message.add_reaction("⛔")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because

```
NOW_WORD = "\n".join(config.WORDS)
```

here you are combining all the words into the NOW_WORD

instead of assigning a "NOW_WORD" you should be able to use "word" in the for loop as "NOW_WORD".